# Jetpack Compose: How to make all items in a FlowRow the same height

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, height, flowlayout

I have some dynamic `Text` Composables laid out in a `FlowRow`, but I can't seem to get them to be the same height. With a normal `Row`, you can use `.height(Intrinsic.Min)` on the Row in conjunction with `.fillMaxHeight()` on the children, but I can't get that to work with the `FlowRow`.
The documentation of [Flow Layouts](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/layouts/flow?hl=en#individual-item) talks about alignment of items with different heights within the FlowRow, but it doesn't mention how to make them all the same height. Maybe I missed something?

Here's a code example. I commented out where I tried intrinsic height along with fillMaxHeight:

```
import androidx.compose.foundation.background
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Arrangement
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.ExperimentalLayoutApi
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.FlowRow
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.IntrinsicSize
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxHeight
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.height
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.width
import androidx.compose.material.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp


@OptIn(ExperimentalLayoutApi::class)
@Preview(showBackground = true, widthDp = 400)
@Composable
private fun FlowRowPreview() {
    val textModifier = Modifier.width(185.dp).background(Color.Red)//.fillMaxHeight()
    FlowRow(
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Absolute.SpaceBetween,
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(16.dp),
        modifier = Modifier//.height(IntrinsicSize.Min)
    ) {
        Text(modifier = textModifier, text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam")
        Text(modifier = textModifier, text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit")
        Text(modifier = textModifier, text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit")
        Text(modifier = textModifier, text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit")
    }
}
```

What the Code currently shows:
[image: Preview of how code is currently]

What the code shows when I uncomment `.height(IntrinsicSize.Min)` and `.fillMaxHeight()`:
[image: Preview when I uncomment the height modifiers]

What I actually want:
[image: Preview of expected behavior]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest version of FlowRow and FlowColumn (1.7.0-alpha03) should now have a modifier:

Modifier.fillMaxRowHeight(fraction)
Modifier.fillMaxColumnWidth(fraction)

That should solve this.

https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/layout/FlowRowScope#(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier).fillMaxRowHeight(kotlin.Float)

https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/layout/FlowColumnScope#(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier).fillMaxColumnWidth(kotlin.Float)

Comment: YEEEEEEEES! This is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks mate!

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to get all the heights of the items and once they are all displayed I find the maximum height and apply it to all of them. Here is the code:

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalLayoutApi::class)
@Composable
private fun FlowRowPreview() {
    val lorem = "" +
            "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, " +
            "sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. " +
            "Ut enim ad minim"

    // Container to store all heights
    val heightsMap = mutableMapOf<Int, Int>() // map instead of list to avoid side effects
    
    // Will recompose views once the value is changed
    val finalHeightBlock = remember { mutableIntStateOf(0) } // final height to set
    
    // Data we are going to 
    val data = listOf(
        lorem,
        lorem.substring(0, lorem.length / 2),
        lorem.substring(0, lorem.length / 2),
        lorem.substring(0, lorem.length / 2),
    ).mapIndexed { index, text ->
        index to text
    }
    
    // Block for storing heights and calling recompose once all heights are stored
    val reportHeight: (Int, Int) -> Unit = { index, height ->
        heightsMap[index] = height

        if (heightsMap.size == data.size) {
            finalHeightBlock.intValue = heightsMap.maxOf { it.value }
        }
    }

    FlowRow(
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Absolute.SpaceBetween,
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(16.dp),
    ) {
        data.forEach {
            FlowText(it.second, it.first, finalHeightBlock, reportHeight)
        }
    }
}

@Composable
private fun FlowText(
    lorem: String,
    index: Int,
    height: MutableIntState,
    reportHeight: (Int, Int) -> Unit,
) {
    val modifier = if (height.intValue > 0) {
        Modifier
            .width(185.dp)
            .height(height.intValue.pxToDp())
            .background(Color.Red)
    } else {
        Modifier
            .width(185.dp)
            .wrapContentHeight()
            .background(Color.Red)
            .onGloballyPositioned { it ->
                reportHeight(index, it.size.height)
            }
    }

    Text(
        modifier = modifier,
        text = lorem
    )
}

@Composable
fun Int.pxToDp(): Dp {
    val density = LocalDensity.current.density
    return (this / density).dp
}
```

Preview:
[image]

Comment: I considered tracking the largest height then setting boxes to that height, but there are a couple issues with this: 1. it's kind of hacky because compose is not built to measure twice, and this side-steps that rule 2. I don't want all of the boxes the same size. I want each row to have boxes the same size, but each row should act independently of the others. See last screenshot of original question.

Comment: Is `FlowRow` needed here? How many items will be displayed in the row?

Comment: I found a decent solution that doesn't use FlowRow. I just wanted to know if it was possible to do this with a FlowRow since that API is cleaner. I don't think this is currently possible with a FlowRow